# Toggle menu between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help please.

I wrote this code : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/t275kvbj/12/)

When I click on the hamburger icon that's work fine, the menu open and close well. 
When I click on "Contact" that's work fine too. I can close the "Overlay contact page" with the hamburger icon (who represents a cross) or to click again on "Contact".

But when I click on the hamburger icon (ok that's open the menu) and then that I click again on "Contact", that's don't work fine :

```
1 > the hamburger icon isn't a cross
2 > if I click again on "Contact" I would like to close the "Overlay contact page"
```

Can you help me please ?

```
$('.toggle-menu-mobile').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.icon-menu-mobile').toggleClass('is-opened is-closed');

    if ($('#overlay-contact-mobile').is(':visible')) {
        $('#overlay-contact-mobile').toggle();
    } else {
        $('#overlay-menu-mobile').toggle();
    }
});

$('.toggle-contact-mobile').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.icon-menu-mobile').toggleClass('is-closed is-opened');

    $('#overlay-contact-mobile').toggle();

});
```

Comment: This line `if ($('#overlay-contact').is(':visible')) {` means that `$('#overlay-contact').toggle();` is only done if it's "visible", not if it's "hidden", or?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.toggle-menu-mobile').click(function() {
    $('.icon-menu-mobile').toggleClass('is-opened');
    $('#overlay-menu-mobile').slideToggle();
    $('#overlay-contact-mobile').slideUp();
});

$('.toggle-contact-mobile').click(function() {
    $('.icon-menu-mobile').removeClass('is-opened');
    $('#overlay-contact-mobile').slideToggle();
    $('#overlay-menu-mobile').slideUp();
});
```